# Use aws cli to add a statement to an existing S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Assuming I already have a policy attached to a bucket, in the likes of:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9876543211:someuser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update this policy, so that I enforce SSL (i.e. I want the statement above to remain intact).

How can I use `aws` cli so that my policy ends up looking like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9876543211:someuser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect":"Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition":{
                "Bool":
                { "aws:SecureTransport": false }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: did you try ```aws organizations update-policy```  with --content option for your json?
refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/update-policy.html

Comment: You need to get the existing policy, append new statement and then update bucket policy with new policy. It would be easier to achieve using a programming language like Python (using boto3 SDK) rather than using aws cli.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to attach\update Inline policy, You can use the [aws iam put-role-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/put-role-policy.html) command.

Description:

> Adds or updates an inline policy document that is embedded in the
>   specified IAM role.

usage:

```
cat > policy-name.json << EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1572432380474",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF

aws iam put-role-policy \
--role-name ${ROLE_NAME} \
--policy-name policy-name \
--policy-document file://policy-name.json
```

In case you want to update Managed policy, use [aws organizations update-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/update-policy.html) command.

Description:

> Updates an existing policy with a new name, description, or content.
>   If you don't supply any parameter, that value remains unchanged. You
>   can't change a policy's type.

usage:

```
aws organizations update-policy \
    --policy-id policy-id \
    --content "{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9876543211:someuser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect":"Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition":{
                "Bool":
                { "aws:SecureTransport": false }
            }
        }
    ]
}
"
```